# Transparent alpha mode in Shader Graph creates unwanted jagged outline

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I am currently working on a transparent shader and noticed that all my works have a jagged dark outline. I guess I've used the wrong settings somewhere, but I've been fiddling around with a couple settings without any success. I have created a basic shader, which shows the shader settings I use and the problem.

It might be a little hard to see on the screenshot, so please have a look in full resolution. There's a small black outline around the circle on the yellow background.
[image]

Comment: These dark fringes are where your RGB colour is on its way down from white to black, while the alpha isn't yet fully black. So instead of drawing partially-transparent white, you're drawing partially-transparent grey, leaving dark marks on your bright yellow background. Have you tried either bleeding your colour out, so you continue to output full-brightness RGB even in areas where the alpha is falling off, or [using pre-multiplied alpha blending](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/138818/39518) to account for this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your Alpha should use the ellipse output pin.

Your RGB should be one consistent colour, and not darken from the inside of the ellipse to the outside.

For a smoothly-antialiased edge, your AlphaClipThreshold should remain at the default of zero, and you should use Transparent blending rather than Opaque.

[image: Example graph setup]