# Invert the colour of pixels where 1 bit sprites are overlapping

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, sprites, lighting

I have a simple scene in Unity that makes use of some simple art that uses either white or transparent colours to create a 1-bit art design. The image below shows this. [image: A screenshot of the game in question.]

I want to have a that if two sprites overlap then the colour changes to transparent which makes the sprite appear to have its colours inverted. For example, a white cone from a lamppost could look like a beam of light. When the character walks into the beam its colour should change black so it is still visible under the light. As well as this, if the sprite is only partially in the light then only that portion of the sprite should be revealed.

I used a sprite mask and a second sprite hidden behind the first with different sprite mask interaction options to achieve the effect but I also have a variety of particle systems, such as the rain visible above, and would like this to also be affected. I've included a rather crude image of what I am aiming for.

[image]

I believe that I need some sort of shader but am struggling to even know where to start looking so any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can do this by making a custom version of the standard sprite shader (so it still does everything the one you're used to can do), and modifying its blending operation.

Start by going to the [Unity Download Archive](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive), and grab the built-in shaders for the version of Unity you're using. I'm currently on 2020.3.7f1 (LTS)

[image: Downloading built-in shaders]

Inside that zip, you'll want to copy `DefaultResourcesExtra/Sprites-default.shader` - place the copy in your project's `Assets` folder with a new name, like "Sprites-invert.shader"

Now open up the text file and make two modifications:

First, at the very top of the file, change the shader's name to match the name you picked for the file, so it doesn't collide with the built-in shader.

```
Shader "Sprites/Invert"
{
```

Then scroll down to this line:

```
Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

This says "When blending this sprite with the background, the output colour should be the colour of this sprite times 'one', plus the colour already in the frame times 'one minus the alpha value of this sprite'". That gives us what's called [premultiplied alpha blending](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/138818/39518).

We'll change it to this:

```
Blend OneMinusDstColor OneMinusSrcColor
```

Now we're multiplying the foreground colour by the inverse of the background, and the background by the inverse of the foreground. That gives us...

| Foreground | Background | First Term | + | Second Term | = | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 (White) | 0 (Black) | (1) * (1-0) = 1 | + | (0) * (1-1) = 0 | = | 1 (White) |
| 1 (White) | 1 (White) | (1) * (1-1) = 0 | + | (1) * (1-1) = 0 | = | 0 (Black) |
| 0 (Black) | 0 (Black) | (0) * (1-0) = 0 | + | (0) * (1-0) = 0 | = | 0 (Black) |
| 0 (Black) | 1 (White) | (0) * (1-1) = 0 | + | (1) * (1-0) = 1 | = | 1 (White) |

...And for values in between we get greys, so you don't lose your antialiased adges like on that triangular sprite in your mask example.

Make a material that uses your new shader, and assign it to the SpriteRenderer components for your foreground sprites. You'll get a result something like this:

[image: Example]

(Using this ["Sauropod skeleton" icon by Caro Asercion](https://game-icons.net/1x1/caro-asercion/sauropod-skeleton.html) as an example)

You can apply a post effect at the end to remap your colours if you want the white and black to look like something else. This keeps the shader simpler than trying to use those special colour values throughout the pipeline.

What's nice about this is that it has exactly the same cost as the original sprite shader - we didn't add even a single new instruction, just changed the parameters of the blending operation we were already doing anyway That's much cheaper than mask-based solutions that require extra rendering/sampling from the mask texture.

If you have both sprites using the default material and sprites using this new material in your scene, you'll pay a little cost due to splitting them into separate draw calls for each shader. But if you're using this new sprite shader exclusively then it's effectively free.